# What is the faster way to convert an object with property value: "HH:MM:SS" to string "N Minutes"?

Tags: javascript

I have hundred of objects with structure like

```
{
movieName: 'xyz',
time: '02:15:50'
timeAsText: null
}
```

I need to set `timeAsText` with a text as "136 minutes" based on property 'time'.
Seconds should be rounded up.

Could you point me out what could be the faster approach?

Comment: What have you tried already so we know what not to add as an answer? Also, how are the objects held? Are they in an array?

Comment: Are the objects generated on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with two methods ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjfchh9p/1/)); the first using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and the second using a plain `for...loop`. As you can see from the demo the plain loop is considerably faster:

```
var out = [];
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = arr[i];
  var time = obj.time.split(':').map(Number);
  if (time[2] > 0) { time[1]++; }
  obj.timeAsText = (time[0] * 60) + time[1] + ' minutes';
  out.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best to do is probably that, and, seeing the numbers of similar answers, probably the only one.

-first, you use **split(':')** to make your string become a array of parseable string;

-then, parse the value to int. Use **parseInt**
at this time, you should have a array like that

```
 [number_of_hours, number_of_minutes,number_of_second]
```

-then you just have to add the different values like

```
obj.timeAsText = array[0]*60+array[1]+Math.round(array[2]/60)+' minutes';
```

**The full answer :**

```
var arr=obj.time.split(':').forEach(function(entry){
    entry=parseInt(entry);
});
obj.timeAsText= arr[0]*60+arr[1]+Math.round(array[2]/60)+" minutes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var obj = {
        movieName: 'xyz',
        time: '02:15:50'
        timeAsText: null
    }
    var a = obj.time.split(':'); // split it at the colons
    var minutes = parseInt(+a[0]) * 60  + parseInt(+a[1])  + Math.round(parseInt(+a[2])/60); 
    obj.timeAsText = minutes + " minutes";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the fastest, but it's the most easily readable one:

```
var test = {
    movieName: 'xyz',
    time: '02:15:50',
    timeAsText: null
};

test.time.replace(/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/, function(m, p1, p2, p3) {
    // Multiplication and division implicitly converts p1 and p3 to numbers
    return p1*60 + parseInt(p2) + Math.ceil(p3/60);
});
```